# Is there anyway to access system keychain in OS X from objective C

Tags: objective-c, macos, keychain

I am trying to save Password in system keychain but it gives a "write permission error", is there any way to access it as root and save password using AuthorizationRef or anything?

```
+ (int) createItem:(NSString*)label withService:(NSString*)service account:(NSString*)account description:(NSString*)description andPassword:(NSString*)password {

// This variable will hold all sorts of operation status responses
OSStatus status;

// Converting the NSStrings to char* variables which we will need later
const char *labelUTF8 = [label UTF8String];
const char *serviceUTF8 = [service UTF8String];
const char *accountUTF8 = [account UTF8String];
const char *descriptionUTF8 = [description UTF8String];
const char *passwordUTF8 = [password UTF8String];

// This variable is soon to hold the System Keychain
SecKeychainRef keychain = NULL;

status = SecKeychainCopyDomainDefault(kSecPreferencesDomainSystem, &keychain);
if (status == errSecSuccess) {
    NSLog(@"Succeeded opening System Keychain");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Could not obtain System Keychain: %@", SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, NULL));
    return 60;
}

NSLog(@"Unlocking System Keychain");
status = SecKeychainUnlock(keychain, 0, NULL, FALSE);
if (status == errSecSuccess) {
    NSLog(@"Succeeded unlocking System Keychain");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Could not unlock System Keychain: %@", SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, NULL));
    return 61;
}

// This variable is going to hold our new Keychain Item
SecKeychainItemRef item = nil;

SecAccessRef access = nil;
status = SecAccessCreate(CFSTR("Some VPN Test"), (__bridge CFArrayRef)(self.trustedApps), &access);

if(status == noErr) {
    NSLog(@"Created empty Keychain access object");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Could not unlock System Keychain: %@", SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, NULL));
    return 62;
}

// Putting together the configuration options
SecKeychainAttribute attrs[] = {
    {kSecLabelItemAttr, (int)strlen(labelUTF8), (char *)labelUTF8},
    {kSecAccountItemAttr, (int)strlen(accountUTF8), (char *)accountUTF8},
    {kSecServiceItemAttr, (int)strlen(serviceUTF8), (char *)serviceUTF8},
    {kSecDescriptionItemAttr, (int)strlen(descriptionUTF8), (char *)descriptionUTF8},
};

SecKeychainAttributeList attributes = {sizeof(attrs) / sizeof(attrs[0]), attrs};
status = SecKeychainItemCreateFromContent(kSecGenericPasswordItemClass, &attributes, (int)strlen(passwordUTF8), passwordUTF8, keychain, access, &item);
NSLog(@"item %@", item);
if(status == noErr) {
    NSLog(@"Successfully created Keychain Item");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Creating Keychain item failed: %@", SecCopyErrorMessageString(status, NULL));
    return 63;
}

return 0;
```

}

I have also tried to do it with shell script when I give commands to NSTask and launches it, it results in same output. Does anyone have idea about how should it can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//first check if item already exists, if it is - it might cause an error while trying to save data
if([self tryToFetchForService:service account:account])
  [self deleteItemForService:service account:account];
NSDictionary *query=@{(__bridge id)kSecClass:(__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                      (__bridge id)kSecAttrService:service,
                      (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount:account,
                      (__bridge id)kSecValueData:password,
                      (__bridge id)kSecAttrLabel:description};
status=SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query,NULL);
if(status!=errSecSuccess && error!=NULL)
    *error=...; // error initialize
```

You need to include Security-framework.
If you need to delete object from the keychain look below

```
NSDictionary *query=@{(__bridge id)kSecClass:(__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
                      (__bridge id)kSecAttrService:service,
                      (__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount:account,
                      (__bridge id)kSecReturnRef:@YES};
CFTypeRef result=NULL;
status=SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query,&result);
if(status==errSecSuccess)
 {
    status=SecKeychainItemDelete((SecKeychainItemRef)result);
    CFRelease(result); // release core foundation class instance
 }
if(status!=errSecSuccess && error!=NULL)
    *error=...; // failed operation
```

Answer (score 0):

Only an Administrator account can write to the System keychain.

Factor out the code, which accesses the keychain, to an XPC Helper application using [XPC Helper Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html), so that the helper can run with root privileges.